# Strange ClassCastException in findViewById

Tags: android, classloader, classcastexception, android-multidex, dexclassloader

I observe a weird exception thrown on line:

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

the exception looks as follows:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager cannot be cast to android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

I can't reproduce it, but it happens sometimes according to logs.

The app uses official multidex build with gradle.

Comment: I'm having similiar trouble with the official multidex library.

Comment: I am also getting similar exception in DrawerLayout typecasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JLS, `ClassCastException` happens when you try to cast one class to a different class, which is quite obvious.

What is not so obvious is what is **the definition of Class identity**:

1. the classes have to be both of either class, interface or array type,
2. they have to have the same binary name,
3. they have to be loaded by the same effective `ClassLoader`

**In your case multiple `ClassLoader`s will most likely load the same class.**